# Eclipse: The import org.apache.tomcat cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse

I meet this issue when import Maven project use Eclipse.
The import `org.apache.tomcat` can't be resolved    at 3rd line

[image]

Do I need to fix this issue and how?

Comment: Do you have the m2e-wtp feature installed? What have you tried already?

Comment: I do not install m2e-wtp, I only try to re-build as this project work fine for other my colleagues and I already fetch the latest project from git, and use the same .m2 file and setting.xml as them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a dependency issue.

If this is indeed a Maven project validate you are running a version of Eclipse that either has Maven support integrated or install the m2e-wtp feature. Then validate that your pom.xml in your project is adding the right dependency for that tomcat feature.

If this is not a Maven project, try adding a Server Runtime library for Tomcat to your build path.